# using AJV with javascript, how to specify the schema of an array that must have a specific item?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsonschema, json-schema-validator, ajv

```
      cats: {
        type: "array",
        items: {
          type: "string",
          minLength: 1,
        },
        minItems: 3,
      },
```

How do I further specify that the value `"tiger"` must be present in the array, i.e. required?

Comment: https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/array.html#contains